# Fire Simulation, Rotomotion, Compositing

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation, compositing-nodes, fire

I have been working on a music video for a while, and have had this idea of making the artist burn up at the end of the music video.

I have tried with simply making a geometry with armatures to try and match his movements and use it as the emitter for the fire sim, but I saw that the movements didn't really match the borders of the fire. And I forgot to give the geo legs, which didn't really look nice when I did a test render. So now I have decided to start over from scratch. Also, the fire was like super big and looked like a bonfire, so I have been wondering how I can actually make the model more controlled and make it look realistic.

So my question is foremost about making Rotomotion, like matching the movements of the video clip and making a perfect kind of model to match it. Is it simply to just model and animate? Or is there some secrets weapon that will make it easier? With say maybe motion tracking?

I have a reference to another music video that has done this, which is Weekends, I can't feel my face. I will add a link to the vfx breakdown that they made in Maya.

I have also noticed through my first try, that the fire sim in Blender is quite tedious and doesn't bake always, and have problems with the cache. So when I try and make adjustments to the fire emitter, animation of the emitter, or just do something with the fire domain border. It just bugs out and doesn't always re-cache the scene. I have tried also working with a particle system from the model as the emitter, but it never seems to work. It doesn't show any fire.

Weekend VFX breakdown = https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x42pknu
My video CLip = https://youtu.be/B71SpEA44uo

[image: My model so far, I have not begun with the armatures yet.]

Comment: You can use motion tracking, then assign empties to trackers and use those to control an armature, or as hooks to control deformation.

Comment: Sean Kennedy has a few videos that might give you some ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0d1QnS29y0&list=PLW007QhybFgeTIhw4mrnZKRQGqOrREv17